# How to get back a normal DataFrame after invoking groupBy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For a simple `grouping` operation apparently the returned type is *no longer a DataFrame* ??

```
val itemsQtyDf = pkgItemsDf.groupBy($"packageid").withColumn("totalqty",sum("qty"))
```

We can not however invoke the DataFrame ops after the `groupBy` - since it is a `GroupedData`:

```
Error:(26, 55) value withColumn is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData
```

So, then how to get my `DataFrame` back after a grouping?  Is it necessary to use `DataFrame.agg()` instead??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping only without an aggregate function implies you may want to use the `distinct()` function instead which does return a DataFrame. But your example shows you want `sum("qty")`, so just change your code to be like this:

```
pkgItemsDf.groupBy($"packageid").agg(sum("qty").alias("totalqty"))
```